# How to debug a shared library using eclipse/gdb on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, debugging, shared-libraries

At my university we are currently developing a VST-Plugin on Windows using open source tools.

My professor is pretty fond of Microsoft Visual Studio and rather sceptic towards open source tools such as Eclipse, GCC, Subclipse etc.
However, until now I was able to solve all of his problems and it would be a shame if he could not be convinced that this open source toolchain is similarly powerful to his MSVC-environment.

A VST-Plugin is a shared library for audio processing. We use the Tobybear Minihost as our testing application for it and it works just fine. However, we are not able to debug it. We can set breakpoints, but Eclipse does not recognize them when the Minihost opens the Plugin.

Do you know how to debug a shared library using GDB/Eclipse on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be a bug/limitation of GDB on windows

http://synthedit.audioholik.com/index.php?name=Content&pid=8
http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg17618.html

The workaround is force a breakpoint in your code.